# get context login info

Tags: user-profile, user, spcontext

I see all kinds of code to get current SharePoint 2010 logged in user. (I guess current context user from the browser client).

What is the best code? (not currently logged into machine user)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do and from where?  For example, the code for a web part is radically different from a powershell script which is also different from what you would use in a timer job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` will give you the current user `SPUser` object (browser). To get the current user loginname use `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName` .